# Dropdown to display amount of rows before selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#table_id').DataTable({
      initComplete: function() {
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>'),
          table = this;
        select.on("change", function() {
          table.api().column(0).search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
        $("#table_id").closest(".dataTables_wrapper").find(".dataTables_filter").append(select);

        table.api().columns(0).data().eq(0).unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + " - " + getClinicName(d) +  '</option>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I have this code that displays a dropdown box showing the id(shown as d), and the name. I also want it to display the amount of entries in each rows.

**For example :**

if row 2 has 5 entries , then I want it to display id-name-5 rows like `id-name-#ofrows.`

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT");
$rows = pg_num_rows($result);
echo $rows . " row(s) returned.\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use `table.data().count()` to get tables rows count:

```
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + " - " + getClinicName(d) +   " - " + table.data().count() + '</option>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `Count = 0`  and Increase and print  it every time..

```
 $('#table_id').DataTable({
        initComplete: function() {
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>'),
              table = this;
            select.on("change", function() {
                table.api().column(0).search($(this).val()).draw();
            });
            $("#table_id").closest(".dataTables_wrapper").find(".dataTables_filter").append(select);
            @int count = 1;
            table.api().columns(0).data().eq(0).unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + " - " + getClinicName(d) + " row no " + count + '</option>');
                count++; // increase count
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: what was the error ? see in the console if there is

Comment: I saw there wasn't, just my whole dropdown box disappeared.

Comment: Actually, now I put count = 0, and it just displays random numbers, not the actually number of rows

Comment: try var count = 1;  instead @int count = 1;

Comment: I met that if row 2 has 5 entries, then I want it to display id-name-5 rows, not just which number each row is

Comment: any doc about @int count = 1;??

Comment: doc means? actually i dont understand your questions "I also want it to display the amount of entries in each rows." your questions about dropdown and you are talking about amount of entries in each rows

Comment: For example, if id 22 returns 5 rows then I want my dropdown to show

"22-name-5 rows"

Comment: means right now you are getting multiple record for the same id in dropdown and you want merge it for the same id?? and there is no unique id one to many relation?

Comment: No I mean that when i click on the id number 22, I see 3 rows (each contains information about 22), I want to be able to see on my dro-down "22-Name- 3 rows available"